# How to fix error maven ?

Tags: maven

I don't know English, but i need people help me. Why did maven error as picture. Thank! [image]

[image]

Comment: Cause your code contains errors which can't be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Unclosed brackets.

Check whether every `{` has a `}` in App.java

Also, your IDE (for example Eclipse) should show you what's wrong. If you're not using one - start.

Comment: Thank... But i use NotePad++. And i check whether {} in App.java, but i don't wrong.

Comment: Maybe `(` `)` or `[` `]`. Add App.java code to your question, that's where the problem lies as @khmarbaise comment says. And please, get some IDE. Eclipse, IntelliJ or even NetBeans. Your life will be so much easier.